# Surreal numbers in Set theoretic multiverse

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Good day,

I would like to ask this question.

Proper class of surreal numbers is the largest ordered colection in givent Set theoretic universe. Now If we have a set theoretic multiverse as proposed by J.D. Hamkins does that mean that every proper class of surreal numbers is just countable from a "Larger Universe"?

Also may I ask you this: If we don´t demand ordering, can we have larger collections than surreal numbers? Also what has larger cardinality, Proper class of surreal numbers (with cardinality Ord) or some Large cardinal, lets say Mahlo?

Thank you very much,
have a nice day.

Comment: http://karagila.org/2017/dangerous-knowledge-in-the-information-age/

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think that this knowledge would be dangerous. It is a *huge* inspiration for the mathematicians of the future, and it has also a strong effect to popularize science et al. Some similar already happened in the 60s of the USA. Star Trek appeared and filled the brain of the commoners with science babble. Physicists initally opposed it, criticized it. Later they've understood, that although it fills the mind of the people with crap, it also inspires the teenagers to become the physicists of the future.

Comment: @peterh: This is not the same thing. The technical details required to understand Hamkins' approach to the multiverse, as well as its philosophical implications, and the connections to large cardinals are not "a matter of imagination". It's a technical thing that you understand or you don't. It's not some middle ground that "inspires new ideas". I'm not saying that you can't read those things are come up with new ideas, it's just not the same. Set theory and technological inventions are not quite the same thing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I reacted also to your blog post about the half-knowledge. I think the best to do with this question is to properly answer it, on the appearant knowledge level of the OP, but targeting also the google visitors of the future. The inspirational value of such questions is huge.

Comment: @peterh: Yes, I agree. I'll get writing on that 250 page paper.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Man I know you mean well and I understand your frustration with my question as yes this is not my field of expertise, however it is something that i am interested at, so don´t put people down. I am not some teen kid who seeks instant gratification (I mean is there such a thing in mathematics?). I hold undergrad degree in computer science and i am curently graduate student working towards my masters degree. I am just fascinated with large numbers and I would like to understand the hierarchy of ever increasing sizes of cardinal numbers.

Comment: @Pan: I am not the one who compared you to a teenager. Take that with peterh. The point is that you are asking a very naive question, which unfortunately looks like someone who read about of technical concepts in set theory and naive placed them together in a way that doesn't make a lot of sense. Hence, my pointing at dangerous knowledge.

Comment: @AsafKaragila With that I can agree. (the bit about it beeing a naive question that might not make a lot of sense :) ). Also peterh no ofense taken, i got it that you meant very well for me and others who might not always fraze their questions properly.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The thing that I would like to know is this. If we have set theoretic universe V inside which we consider proper class of surreal numbers which has cardinality Ord. Now if we allow inaccesible cardinals in our universe V does that add additional ordinals to our proper class and therefor increase its size? And if yes does this size grows with additional stronger and stronger large cardinal axioms like Mahlo etc?

Comment: No, it just means that there are sets which are the surreal numbers of set-sized models of ZFC, which are themselves in some sense "a toy model" of the actual surreals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila May I ask you what do you mean by actual surreals? There is some absolute class of surreals which I would assume contain all numbers in "existence"? I always thought that you can always add more numbers to your set theoretic universe

Comment: When you work in a specific universe, then there is a single class of all the surreals. If there are inaccessible cardinals, and even without, there will be "mini-surreals", which are sets which are in some sense kind-of like the surreal numbers as a whole. If you want to work in a multiverse setting, especially one such as Hamkins' multiverse with the Countability Axiom, then there's no real sense talking about "the surreal numbers", but rather "the surreal numbers of a universe in the multiverse".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. And can the cardinality of such a class be seen as a measure of the size of the given Universe, or is the given universe in which we are working larger than the class of its surreals? That is of course if it even make sense to talk about size of set theoretic universe.

Comment: Not more than the size of the ordinals tells you something about the size of the universe. Which is really not a whole lot. And as you note, talking about the size of the universe is not very meaningful.

Comment: @AsafKaragila And can there be larger construct in given universe then a Proper class? (As I understand it all proper classes have same size so it doesn´t matter which proper class)

Comment: No, not all proper classes have the same size. You can search on this site for some information. Larger than the universe, no. The universe is *all* the sets, *all* the objects. Classes are just collections of *some of the objects*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No no I didnt mean larger than the universe itselve, I mean if in a given Universe V there can be larger "structures" or lets call them collections then proper classes.

Comment: No. Because there are sets, and that's it. Classes are "artificial constructs" we create to talk about collections of sets. But that's it. Yes, we can formalize these things and make sense into $2$-classes (or hyperclasses), but then you're involving a lot of meta-theory, or just veering into type theory, or into something akin to "end extensions" (e.g. Grothendeick Universes axiom). But then you're also not exactly "in the universe" anymore. There's *a lot* of questions on these topics on the site. Feel free to browse around and search for them to read more. Other than this, learn set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for your time and kind answers. Just one last question, I promise. :) So if we have given set theoretic Universe V, does that universe contain more elements than its surreal numbers, or can the class of surreal numbers be seen as all elements of a given universe? Thank you again

Comment: Well, depending on how you code the surreal numbers into sets. Some axioms guarantee there is a bijection between the surreals and the universe, so you can code the surreal numbers so there is only them. Some axioms guarantee that there isn't such bijection, so there will be more. And sometimes you can just code the surreal numbers, even if there is a bijection, by using a smaller class. The question is sort of meaningless.